# JMeter: Is there a way to insert a time delay between messages sent via TCP Sampler

Tags: jmeter

Our organization is using bare bones JMeter to post MHE messsages to the host environments, using only the TCP Sampler tool. For example, we would have multiple messages in the sampler view to send for receiving - emulating the MHE vendor message to the WMS.  Doing so results in all messages in the window being sent over a the exact same time.  Attempts to add "Constant Time" within the sampler does not prevent all messages from being sent at the same time.  Attempts to try the three settings within Set NoDelay ( blank, Checked, or dash, do not change the behavior.
This timing is causing issues by not mimicking the "real" world scenario, but it is difficult to post individual messages one at a time and achieve near real world timing.

What we are seeking is a way to have each message sent after the previous, by a set amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [TCPClientImpl](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPClientImpl.html) doesn't have any functionality for this, you might want to open connection once and then re-use the connection:

[image]

so you will have a separate [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) per single message and control how often they will be executed using a suitable [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) or [Flow Control Action sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

Otherwise you can come up with your own implementation of [AbstractTCPClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/AbstractTCPClient.html) doing exactly what you need.